# Does Canada Express Entry requires valid job offer and proof funds?

Tags: immigration, canada, skilled-migration

My wife, my 7 year old kid and I are thinking about migrating to Canada for a permanent residence.

We have followed some initial steps and we might be eligible for **Express Entry** .

According to their website these are the documents that can be required (some are optional).

https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/documents.html

**My doubt is that if I get a valid job offer do I still need to provide proof of funds?**

For 3 people that means amount is CAD$ 20.222 which is quite high.

The details about the proof of funds is https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/documents/proof-funds.html#money_needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need proof of funds to meet the minimum requirements of the

- Federal Skilled Worker Program
- Federal Skilled Trades Program

You don’t need to show that you have enough money to support yourself and your family if

- you’re applying under the Canadian Experience Class or
- you’re authorized to work in Canada **and** you have a valid job offer, even if you apply under the Federal Skilled Worker Program or the Federal Skilled Trades Program

Source: https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/documents/proof-funds.html

Comment: So for Federal Skilled Worker Program funds is enough, no need to have valid job offer ? I have read that document (I provided the link in my question) but is still not very clear if having BOTH is required or it will just improve my score but is not required to have BOTH

Comment: As I understand it, having a valid job offer is not one of the minimum requirements, but it is one of the selection factors so will improve your score (by up to 10 points) https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/eligibility/federal-skilled-workers/six-selection-factors-federal-skilled-workers.html

Comment: The same applies for the Funds, they provide score ? or do I need to have the CAD$20.000 ?

Comment: Proof of funds isn’t a selection factor, so does not score any points

Comment: The document clearly says "This table shows the minimum amount you need to immigrate to Canada. If you have more money, you should list the full amount in your profile or application." - also says "The funds must be available both when you apply and when (if) we issue you a permanent resident visa. You must prove to an immigration officer that you can legally access the money to use here when you arrive.

For proof, you must get official letters from any banks or financial institutions where you’re keeping money."

Comment: Please focus on the question ;-) - "do I need to have the CAD$20.000 ? could it be less ?

Comment: The table shows the minimum amount, so no, it can’t be less